# How to i get my textbox to only allow numbers 1-14?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is what i have so far, but I am obviously getting an error.

```
try
{
    dblNights = Convert.ToDouble(txtNights.Text);

    if (dblNights > 1 && 14)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        string script = "alert(\"Number of Nights Must be between 1 and 14!\");";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        txtNights.Focus();
    }
}//End Try

catch
{
    string script = "alert(\"Number of Nights Must be an Integer!\");";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);

    txtNights.Focus();
}//End Catch
```

I am not quite sure what to do to make show an error box if numbers besides 1-14 are entered. Everything else is working, just not that. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Your `if` is not correct. It should be something like `if(dblNights >=1 && dblNights<=14) //doSomething`

Comment: Can I ask why not use the ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator Control? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @PhilVallone Probably because simply fixing the `if` will solve this.

Comment: Don't use try catch like this, this is terrible style. Use int.TryParse instead.

Comment: @admdrew - I was just thinking the RegularExpressionValidator is a lot less code and no need to call ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Comment: @PhilVallone Yes, totally. He could implement both, given his example above is server-side, and your solution is client-side.

Comment: @admdrew - my rule of thumb is go client-side if you can. Less trips to the server, especially for form validation.

Comment: @PhilVallone I agree that client-side validation is helpful, but typically you back it up with server-side validation as well, if it's necessary for your application. You just can't always guarantee the client will actually follow that validation (those pesky hackers never seem to).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem :** You are not properly using the `Logical AND` operator.

This:

```
       if (dblNights > 1 && 14)
        {

        }
```

Must be:

```
       if (dblNights >= 1 && dblNights <= 14)
        {
             /*valid range some thing here*/
        }
```

**EDIT:** as suggested by Eric Lippert in comments i would like to show you usage of `TryParse`.

if you use `double.TryParse()` you can eliminate the `Exceptions` which may occur with invalid data.because `double.TryParse()` method would return the `Boolean` value `true` if the conversion is successful  otherwise it returns `false` so that you could avoid `try catch` blocks.

Try This:

```
        double dblNights;
        if (double.TryParse(txtNights.Text, out dblNights))
        {
            //conversion is successfull
        }
        else
        {
            //conversion is Failed
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have used a RangeValidator

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_rangevalidator.asp

Save's you the trouble of reinventing the wheel. You can set it's Type property to Integer or Double and not have to worry about parsing values just to validate them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use html 5

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="14" />
```